# OctopusDeploy: Create release step fails with error "feed returned an unexpected status code '403 '"

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy

I have a TeamCity/OctopusDeploy integration that used to work just fine before, but suddenly fails without anything having be changed in the configuration.

The only thing that changed is that both TeamCity and OctopusDeploy were updated in the meantime. Does anyone have any idea what causes this, and how can I fix it?

Here's a log of the last successful build:

```
Step 5/5: OctopusDeploy: Create release (22s)
[Step 5/5] Octopus Deploy (21s)
[Octopus Deploy] Running command: octo.exe create-release --server http://localhost:8888/octopus --apikey SECRET --project Test Configuration Dev --enableservicemessages --version 0.0.0-develop.10 --deployto Test Environment --progress --package DemoFetcher:0.0.0-develop.10
[Octopus Deploy] Creating Octopus Deploy release
[Octopus Deploy] Octopus Deploy Command Line Tool, version 5.2.6
[Octopus Deploy] 
[Octopus Deploy] Detected automation environment: "TeamCity/2018.2.4"
[Octopus Deploy] Space name unspecified, process will run in the default space context
[Octopus Deploy] Handshaking with Octopus Server: http://localhost:8888/octopus
[Octopus Deploy] Handshake successful. Octopus version: 2019.3.1; API version: 3.0.0
[Octopus Deploy] Authenticated as: Admin <admin@company.com> 
[Octopus Deploy] This Octopus Server supports channels
[Octopus Deploy] Finding project: Test Configuration Dev
[Octopus Deploy] Automatically selecting the best channel for this release...
[Octopus Deploy] Building a release plan for Channel 'Default'...
[Octopus Deploy] Finding deployment process...
[Octopus Deploy] Finding release template...
[Octopus Deploy] The package version for some steps was not specified. Going to try and resolve those automatically...
[Octopus Deploy] Finding latest package for step: Install Company Test App Config Service
[Octopus Deploy] Selected 'TestApp.test' version '0.0.0-develop.10' for 'Install Company Test App Config Service'
[Octopus Deploy] Selected the release plan for Channel 'Default' - it is a perfect match
[Octopus Deploy] Using version number provided on command-line: 0.0.0-develop.10
[Octopus Deploy] Release plan for Test Configuration Dev 0.0.0-develop.10
[Octopus Deploy] Channel: 'Default' (this is the default channel)
[Octopus Deploy] # Name Version Source Version rules 
[Octopus Deploy] --- ------------------------------------------------------- ------------------ ------------------ -------------------
[Octopus Deploy] 1 Install Company Test App Config Service 0.0.0-develop.10 Latest available Allow any version 
[Octopus Deploy] 
[Octopus Deploy] Creating release...
[Octopus Deploy] Release 0.0.0-develop.10 created successfully!
[Octopus Deploy] ##teamcity[setParameter name='octo.releaseNumber' value='0.0.0-develop.10']
[Octopus Deploy] Deploying Test Configuration Dev "0.0.0-develop.10" to: Test Environment (Guided Failure: Not Enabled)
[Octopus Deploy] Waiting for 1 deployment(s) to complete....
[Octopus Deploy] Success: Acquire packages
[Octopus Deploy] Success: Step 2: Install Company Test App Config Service
[Octopus Deploy] Success: Apply retention policy on Tentacles
[Octopus Deploy] Deploy Test Configuration Dev release 0.0.0-develop.10 to Test Environment: Success
[Octopus Deploy] Done!
[Octopus Deploy] Octo.exe exit code: 0
```

By contrast, here's a log of the first failing build:

```
Step 6/6: OctopusDeploy: Create release (2s)
[Step 6/6] Octopus Deploy (1s)
[Octopus Deploy] Running command: octo.exe create-release --server http://localhost:8888/octopus --apikey SECRET --project Test Configuration Dev --enableservicemessages --version 0.0.0-develop.17 --deployto Test Environment --progress --package DemoFetcher:0.0.0-develop.17
[Octopus Deploy] Creating Octopus Deploy release
[Octopus Deploy] Octopus Deploy Command Line Tool, version 5.2.6
[Octopus Deploy] 
[Octopus Deploy] Detected automation environment: "TeamCity/2019.1"
[Octopus Deploy] Space name unspecified, process will run in the default space context
[Octopus Deploy] Handshaking with Octopus Server: http://localhost:8888/octopus
[Octopus Deploy] Handshake successful. Octopus version: 2019.3.3; API version: 3.0.0
[Octopus Deploy] Authenticated as: Admin <admin@company.com> 
[Octopus Deploy] This Octopus Server supports channels
[Octopus Deploy] Finding project: Test Configuration Dev
[Octopus Deploy] Automatically selecting the best channel for this release...
[Octopus Deploy] Building a release plan for Channel 'Default'...
[Octopus Deploy] Finding deployment process...
[Octopus Deploy] Finding release template...
[Octopus Deploy] The package version for some steps was not specified. Going to try and resolve those automatically...
[Octopus Deploy] Finding latest package for step: Install Company Test App Config Service
[Octopus Deploy] Octopus Server returned an error: The V2 feed at 'http://collaboration.company.de/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/_Root/default/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='TestApp.test'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' returned an unexpected status code '403 '.
[Octopus Deploy] Server exception: 
[Octopus Deploy] The V2 feed at 'http://collaboration.company.de/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/_Root/default/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='TestApp.test'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' returned an unexpected status code '403 '.
[Octopus Deploy] NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException
[Octopus Deploy] at NuGet.Protocol.V2FeedParser.<>c__DisplayClass53_0.<LoadXmlAsync
[Octopus Deploy] at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.ProcessResponseAsync
[Octopus Deploy] at NuGet.Protocol.V2FeedParser.LoadXmlAsync
[Octopus Deploy] at NuGet.Protocol.V2FeedParser.QueryV2Feed
[Octopus Deploy] at NuGet.Protocol.V2FeedParser.FindPackagesByIdAsync
[Octopus Deploy] at NuGet.Protocol.PackageMetadataResourceV2Feed.GetMetadataAsync
[Octopus Deploy] at Octopus.Shared.Util.TaskExtensions.PrepareForRethrow(Exception exception)
[Octopus Deploy] at Octopus.Shared.Util.TaskExtensions.SafeResult[T](Task`1 task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[Octopus Deploy] at Octopus.Core.Packages.NuGet.ExternalHttpNuGetPackageFeed.FetchPackageMetadataForAllVersionsExpensive(String packageId, Boolean allowPreRelease, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[Octopus Deploy] at Octopus.Core.Packages.NuGet.ExternalHttpNuGetPackageFeed.ListVersions(String packageId, CancellationToken cancellationToken, PackageVersionSearchOptions searchOptions, Int32& total, Int32 skip, Int32 take, Boolean includeReleaseNotes)
[Octopus Deploy] at Octopus.Server.Web.Api.Actions.PackageSearchActionOld.Search(String feedId, String packageId, Boolean partialMatch, Boolean includeMultipleVersions, Boolean includeNotes, Int32 take, PackageVersionSearchOptions searchOptions, Boolean descriptionsOptional)
[Octopus Deploy] at Octopus.Server.Web.Api.Actions.PackageSearchActionOld.ExecuteRegistered()
[Octopus Deploy] at Octopus.Server.Web.Infrastructure.Api.Responder`1.Respond(TDescriptor options, NancyContext context)
[Octopus Deploy] at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
[Octopus Deploy] at Octopus.Server.Web.Infrastructure.OctopusNancyModule.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<get_Routes>b__1(Object x)
[Octopus Deploy] at Nancy.Routing.Route.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3(Object parameters, CancellationToken context)
[Octopus Deploy] -----------------------
[Octopus Deploy] 
[Octopus Deploy] Error from Octopus Server (HTTP 500 InternalServerError)
[Octopus Deploy] Exit code: -7
[Octopus Deploy] Octo.exe exit code: -7
[Step 6/6] Unable to create or deploy release. Please check the build log for details on the error.
[Step 6/6] Unable to create or deploy release. Please check the build log for details on the error.
[Step 6/6] Step OctopusDeploy: Create release failed
```

---

**Update 14-Jun-2019:**

When trying to manually create a release in Octopus Deploy, the following matching error message is displayed:

```
The V2 feed at 'http://collaboration.company.de/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/_Root/default/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='TestApp.test'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' returned an unexpected status code '403 '.
```

This sounds like an Authentication Problem. I think I found the end on OctopusDeploy at Library -> External Feeds -> TeamCity Packages -> Credentials. However, I don't know where the matching end  to configure the credentials in TeamCity is hidden. It does not appear to be in the Deployment Steps. Does anyone know where to configure this?

Comment: The logs are for 2 different steps. Otherwise navigate to your NuGet server and check the expected nuget package version exists.

Comment: Those  logs are for the same step. We only added a testing step in the pipeline before that,but I don't see how this could be the issue. Also, I already verified that the package exists in the repository. I can find `0.0.0-develop.17` in the octopus library just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your package changed from:

```
--package DemoFetcher:0.0.0-develop.10
```

to:

```
--package DemoFetcher:0.0.0-develop.17
```

and second job cant find this package:

```
http://collaboration.company.de/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/_Root/default/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='TestApp.test'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' returned an unexpected status code '403 '
```

Revert your package or verify all packages exist on your NuGet server.

Comment: That the package version changed is expected behaviour. This worked before with various versions up to `DemoFetcher:0.0.0-develop.10`. Also, I already verified that the package `DemoFetcher:0.0.0-develop.17` exists in the feed in the Octopus Library.

Comment: Verify that you have this package: 'TestApp.test&semVerLevel=2.0.0' This is what's failing the installation

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I now figured it out, and it turned out to be a two-layer problem, that was easily resolved once I figured out what was the problem.

The superficial problem was that the "octopus" login in TeamCity that OctopusDeploy used to access the TeamCity Packages feed was no longer working.

However, the actual problem was that the build configuration in OctopusDeploy tried to use the TeamCity Packages feed in the first place, even though the package was pushed to the internal OctopusDeploy feed during an earlier build step.

I now managed to fix this by changing the `Package feed` in the  `Package Details` of the affected deployment steps in the `Process` of the "Test Configuration Dev" project from "TeamCity Packages" to "Octopus Server (built-in)".

Now it works.

So summed up: If you have this problem, try using the internal octopus feed as a package source since it's easier to configure.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason why this happened:

For some reason, Octopus was configured to look for the package in the TeamCity feed, while TeamCity was pushing the Package to the Octopus Feed. I fixed this by telling Octopus to take the package from the integrated Octopus Feed instead of the TeamCity  feed, and now it works.

What confuses me now is how this could possibly have worked before, especially since I could not detect any configuration changes in the Audit of either Octopus or TeamCity. But oh well, as long as it works now, that is okay.